# Error using jusbpmp lib

Tags: java

I am trying to access USB ports in Java. I am using Jusbpmp 0.1.5 with Java 1.7.0_45. I tried testing it in Mac OS X I got the following error.

```
java.lang.Exception: Unknown OS

at jpmp.manager.DeviceManager.loadPmpLib(Unknown Source)
at jpmp.manager.DeviceManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at jpmp.manager.DeviceManager.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at USB.main(USB.java:12)
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import jpmp.device.UsbDevice;
import jpmp.manager.DeviceManager;
import jpmp.notifier.IDeviceTransferNotifier;
import jpmp.notifier.IParseTreeNotifier;

public class USB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try{
           DeviceManager dm = DeviceManager.getInstance();
           dm.createInstance();
           dm.scanDevices();
           Iterator it = dm.getDeviceList().keySet().iterator();
           String devkey = (String)it.next();
           UsbDevice usbdev = (UsbDevice)dm.getDeviceList().get(devkey);
            System.out.println(usbdev.dump());
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Throwable e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
   //USB 연결확인 함수
   static boolean isConnected(String filterProductName, String filterProductid, String filterVendorid){
       try {

           DeviceManager dm;
           dm = DeviceManager.getInstance();
           dm.createInstance();
           dm.scanDevices();

           if (dm.getDeviceList() != null && dm.getDeviceList().size() > 0) {
               for (Iterator it = dm.getDeviceList().keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                   String devkey = (String) it.next();
                   UsbDevice usbdev = (UsbDevice) dm.getDeviceList().get(devkey);
                   if ((usbdev.getPid().equals(filterProductid) && usbdev.getVid().equals(filterVendorid)) || usbdev.getName().equals(filterProductName)) {
                       return true;
                   }
               }
           }
       } catch (Throwable ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       return false;
   } 
   //USB 파일전송 함수
   static void TransUsb() throws Throwable{
       DeviceManager dm = DeviceManager.getInstance();
       dm.createInstance();
       dm.scanDevices();

       String filterProductid = "0x2211";  //productid
       String filterVendorid = "0x0ea0";   //vendorid 

       UsbDevice usbdevFound = null; 
       if (dm.getDeviceList() != null  && dm.getDeviceList().size()>0){
           for ( Iterator it = dm.getDeviceList().keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
               String devkey = (String)it.next();
               UsbDevice usbdev = (UsbDevice)dm.getDeviceList().get(devkey);
               if (usbdev.getPid().equals(filterProductid) && usbdev.getVid().equals(filterVendorid)){
                   usbdevFound = usbdev;

               }
           }
       }

       if (usbdevFound != null) {
           String fileToSend = "C:\\videofile.avi";
           usbdevFound.sendFile(fileToSend, "/Video", null, null);
       }

       dm.releaseInstance();
   } 
}
```

The error happens on the line:

```
DeviceManager dm = DeviceManager.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [jusbpmp home page](https://code.google.com/p/jusbpmp/) (emphasis mine):

> Jusbpmp is a Java library that allows to communicate with portable USB players (supporting MSC or MTP) **on Linux or Windows**.

So it appears this library does not work with Mac OS.

An alternative would be to use [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/), which explicitly support Linux, OS X and Windows:

> Supported platforms are Linux (x86 32/64 bit, ARM 32 bit), OS X (x86 32/64 bit) and Windows (x86 32/64 bit). But other platforms may work as well (as long as they have at least Java 6 and are supported by libusb) by compiling the JNI library manually.

Comment: i know mac is based on linux. linux isn't include mac?

Comment: @housekipper [See this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/11392) which explains the difference between Mac and Linux.